# questions about \xpatchcmd, \ProcessKeysOptions in l3keys2e package, \ProcessKeysOptions in kvoptions package and \widowpenalties

Tags: xpatch, kvoptions

i use nowidow package and \setnowidow, but some case it work not fine:
[image]

for example, i hope paragraph can do page break at red place, but it doesn't.

Then I test, if I change `nowidow.sty`, make `\widowpenalties 2 10000 0` to `\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0`, it can work fine.

```
\newcommand{\setnowidow}[1][\nowidow@defaultlines]{%
    \mathchardef\nowidowmax#1\relax
    % \widowpenalties #1 \nowidow@X{1} 0\par <-- before it's
    \widowpenalties \numexpr(#1)+1 \nowidow@X{1} -1 0\par % <-- after i change
}
```

so I try many ways to patch it (not change the nowidow.sty directly), but all failed.

**Way1**: I use `\xpatchcmd`, not success:

```
\xpatchcmd\setnowidow{\widowpenalties #1 \nowidow@X{1} 0\par}{\widowpenalties \numexpr(#1)+1 \nowidow@X{1} -1 0\par}{}{}
```

**Q1**: why it can't success?

---

**Way2**:
I try `\renewcommand`, it also failed:
MWE:
my main tex `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paper=a5]{zztj}

\begin{document}

abc

\end{document}
```

my customed package `zztj.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{zztj}{}{}{}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

%---
\RequirePackage{nowidow}
\renewcommand{\setnowidow}[1][\nowidow@defaultlines]{%
    \mathchardef\nowidowmax#1\relax
    \widowpenalties \numexpr(#1)+1 \nowidow@X{1} -1 0\par
}

\setnowidow

% --------my other options--------
\tl_new:N\g__zztj_paper_tl
\keys_define:nn{zztj/option}
{
  paper.choices:nn=
    {a4, a5}
    {\tl_gset:Nn\g__zztj_paper_tl{#1}},
}

\ProcessKeysOptions{zztj/option}
```

build error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_par:D 
l.15 \tl_new:N
              \g__zztj_paper_tl
?
```

**Q2**: why have this error?

---

**Way3**: so I copy the source from `nowidow.sty`, and change it, but can't success also, because I use `l3keys2e` package also:
MWE:
my customed package `zztj.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{zztj}{}{}{}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

% --------start copy from nowidow--------
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
   family=nowidow,
   prefix=nowidow@,
}
\DeclareStringOption[2]{defaultlines}
\DeclareBoolOption{all}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\def\nowidow@X#1{%
    \ifnum#1<\nowidowmax
        10000
        \expandafter\nowidow@X\expandafter{%
           \the\numexpr(#1)+1\expandafter\relax\expandafter}%
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\setnowidow}[1][\nowidow@defaultlines]{%
    \mathchardef\nowidowmax#1\relax
    \widowpenalties \numexpr(#1)+1 \nowidow@X{1} -1 0\par
}
\ifnowidow@all
   \setnowidow
\fi
\newcommand{\nowidow}[1][\nowidow@defaultlines]{%
    \begingroup
    \setnowidow[#1]
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\setnoclub}[1][\nowidow@defaultlines]{%
    \mathchardef\nowidowmax#1\relax
    \clubpenalties \numexpr(#1)+1 \nowidow@X{1} -1 0\par
}
\ifnowidow@all
   \setnoclub
\fi
\newcommand{\noclub}[1][\nowidow@defaultlines]{%
    \begingroup
    \setnoclub[#1]
    \endgroup
}
% --------end copy from nowidow--------

\setnowidow

% --------my other options--------
\tl_new:N\g__zztj_paper_tl
\keys_define:nn{zztj/option}
{
  paper.choices:nn=
    {a4, a5}
    {\tl_gset:Nn\g__zztj_paper_tl{#1}},
}

\ProcessKeysOptions{zztj/option}
```

build error:

```
! Package keyval Error: paper undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.14 \ProcessKeyvalOptions*
```

**Q3**: why have this error?

---

**Way4**: I input `\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0` directly, It still can't success:
my customed package `zztj.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{zztj}{}{}{}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

%---
\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0

% --------my other options--------
\tl_new:N\g__zztj_paper_tl
\keys_define:nn{zztj/option}
{
  paper.choices:nn=
    {a4, a5}
    {\tl_gset:Nn\g__zztj_paper_tl{#1}},
}

\ProcessKeysOptions{zztj/option}
```

build error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_global:D 
l.9 \tl_new:N\g__zztj_paper_tl
```

**Q4**: why `\widowpenalties` still fail?

---

**Q5**: what's the good way to patch the `\setnowidow` command but don't change the `nowidow.sty` directly?

Comment: I don't get any error from using `\usepackage{nowidow}\usepackage{xpatch} \makeatletter\xpatchcmd\setnowidow{\widowpenalties #1 \nowidow@X{1} 0\par}{\widowpenalties \numexpr(#1)+1\relax \nowidow@X{1} -1 0\par}{}{\GenericError{}{failed}{}{}}\makeatother`

Comment: Can you please create a complete minimal example of your first approach in which it fails for you?

Comment: yes, no error, but the patch not effective. I'll try to build the problem MWE and post it.

Comment: @Skillmon Please check my new question [why \widowpenalties work not fine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676927/why-widowpenalties-work-not-fine) with MWE.

Comment: The problem is the Latex3 ignore spaces in `\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0`. Please check the answer in this question [Why can't \widowpenalties be put in the preamble?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676727/why-cant-widowpenalties-be-put-in-the-preamble).