# Why can't \widowpenalties be put in the preamble?

Tags: latex3, widows-orphans

Package file `zztj.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{zztj}{}{}{}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

% --------------------------------
\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0

% --------my other options--------
\tl_new:N\g__zztj_paper_tl
\keys_define:nn{zztj/option}
{
  paper.choices:nn=
    {a4, a5}
    {\tl_gset:Nn\g__zztj_paper_tl{#1}},
}

\ProcessKeysOptions{zztj/option}
```

and the test file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[paper=a5]{zztj}

\begin{document}

abc

\end{document}
```

produces this build error:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo)) (./zztj.sty
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)))
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_global:D 
l.10 \tl_new:N\g__zztj_paper_tl
                               
?
```

If I want to put the `\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0` in my package, because I want to manage all the settings in my package, how can this error be solved?

Answer (score 6):

When you declare `\ProvideExplPackage`, `\ExplSyntaxOn` is implicitly in effect, so spaces are ignored and you're basically saying

```
\widowpenalties 310000 -10
```

which asks TeX to look for 310000 numbers, but only one is found.

Either you use a “real” space, which under the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` is `~` (a tilde character)

```
\widowpenalties 3 ~ 10000 ~ -1 ~ 0 \scan_stop:
```

or delay the setting at the end of the package after `\ExplSyntaxOff`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{zztj}{}{}{}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

% --------------------------------
% --------my other options--------
\tl_new:N\g__zztj_paper_tl
\keys_define:nn{zztj/option}
{
  paper.choices:nn=
    {a4, a5}
    {\tl_gset:Nn\g__zztj_paper_tl{#1}},
}

\ProcessKeysOptions{zztj/option}

% other expl3 code

\ExplSyntaxOff

\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0
```

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the `-1` penalty, though: this is essentially the same as `\widowpenalty 10000`.

It might be useful to add “syntactic sugar” for easier input without bothering about spaces (I guess that one day there will be an official `expl3` interface):

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \redmoon_widowpenalties:n
 {
  \widowpenalties \clist_count:n { #1 } ~ \clist_use:nn { #1 } { ~ } \scan_stop:
 }

\redmoon_widowpenalties:n { 10000, -1, 0 }
```

Comment: For the benefit of those with hard-to-read screens: The added characters are tildes, not hyphens.

Comment: @rallg I added it to my answer, thanks for noting.

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much! For you question why I add `-1` penalty, please check my new question [why \widowpenalties work not fine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676927/why-widowpenalties-work-not-fine) with MWE.