# why \widowpenalties work not fine?

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

I set `\widowpenalties 2 10000 0`, but it work not fine:
[image]

I hope page can break at red place, but it doesn't.

If I change `\widowpenalties 2 10000 0` to `\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0`, it can work fine.

MWE:

package file `zztj.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{zztj}{}{}{}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\RequirePackage{paracol}
\RequirePackage[showframe]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}

%--------------------------------
% \widowpenalties~3~10000~-1~0 % if use this, page will break at the position i hope
\widowpenalties~2~10000~0

%--------------------------------
\geometry{a5paper,includehead=true,top=1.7cm,left=1.5cm,bottom=1.7cm,right=1.5cm}
\spaceskip=0.5em
\linespread{1.35}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\raggedbottom
\sloppy

\setCJKfamilyfont{fandolsong}{FandolSong}
\setCJKfamilyfont{fandolhei}{FandolHei}
\setCJKfamilyfont{fandolkai}{FandolKai}

\newcommand{\zztjfandolsong}{\CJKfamily+{fandolsong}}
\newcommand{\zztjfandolhei}{\CJKfamily+{fandolhei}}
\newcommand{\zztjfandolkai}{\CJKfamily+{fandolkai}}

\newcommand{\fandolsongti}{\zztjfandolsong}
\newcommand{\fandolheiti}{\zztjfandolhei}
\newcommand{\fandolkaishu}{\zztjfandolkai}

\newcommand\zztjsectionfont[1]{\titleformat{\section}[display]{#1}{}{0pt}{}}
\newcommand\jnyuan[2][]{\zztjsectionfont{\fandolheiti}\noindent\zihao{5}\section[#1]{#2}\par}
\newcommand\jnyi[1]{\zztjsectionfont{\fandolheiti}\noindent\zihao{5}\section*{#1}\par}

\newcommand\zhwyuanfont{\zihao{5}\fandolsongti}
\newcommand\zhwyifont{\zihao{-5}\fandolkaishu}
\newcommand\zhwyuan[1]{\zhwyuanfont #1\par\vspace{0.5ex}}
\newcommand\zhwyi[1]{\zhwyifont #1\par\vspace{0.5ex}}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.5ex}{0.5ex}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{12pt}

\newcommand\sectionfont{\zihao{5}\fandolheiti}
\newcommand{\leftcol}[2][2]{
  % -----------------------------------------
  % to get the correct baselineskip
  % because left and right column font size are different
  % is there any other better solution the get the correct baselineskip???
  \ifx#2\jnyuan\sectionfont\empty
  \else\ifx#2\zhwyuan\zhwyuanfont\empty\fi\fi
  % -----------------------------------------
  \ensurevspace{#1\baselineskip}\switchcolumn[0]*#2}
\newcommand{\rightcol}{\switchcolumn[1]}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}
```

book file `book.tex`:

```
\documentclass[openany, zihao=5]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{zztj}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{徙郡国豪桀于茂陵。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{汉武帝强迫各郡、国的富豪和有权势的人迁居茂陵。}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{夏，六月，赦天下。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{夏季，六月，大赦天下。}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{是岁，匈奴且侯单于死；有两子，长为左贤王，次为左大将。左贤王未至，贵人以为有病，更立左大将为单于。左贤王闻之，不敢进；左大将使人召左贤王而让位焉。左贤王辞以病，左大将不听，谓曰：“即不幸死，传之于我。”左贤王许之，遂立，为孤鹿姑单于；以左大将为左贤王。数年，病死；其子先贤掸不得代，更以为日逐王。单于自以其子为左贤王。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{这一年，匈奴且侯单于去世。且侯有两个儿子，长子为左贤王，次子为左大将。且侯死后，左贤王没有及时赶到，匈奴贵族们认为左贤王有病，改立左大将为单于。左贤王听说后，不敢前来王庭。左大将派人将左贤王召来，让位给他。左贤王以自己有病为理由推辞不受，左大将不听，对他说：“如果你不幸死去，再传位给我。”左贤王这才答应，即单于位，称为孤鹿姑单于。封左大将为左贤王。几年后，左贤王病死，其子先贤掸因不能继承左贤王之位，所以改封为日逐王。单于封自己的儿子为左贤王。}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{二年(丙戍、前95)}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{二年(丙戍，公元前95年)}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{春，正月，上行幸回中。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{春季，正月，汉武帝巡游回中。}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{杜周卒，光禄大夫暴胜之为御史大夫。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{杜周去世，汉武帝任命光禄大夫暴胜之为御史大夫。}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{秋，旱。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{秋季，干旱。}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{赵中大夫白公奏穿渠引泾水，首起谷口，尾入栎阳，注渭中，袤二百里，溉田四千五百余顷，因名曰白渠；民得其饶。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{赵国中大夫白公奏请朝廷，从谷口至栎阳挖了一条长二百里的引水渠，将泾河水引到渭中地区，使四千五百余顷农田得到灌溉，因此命名为白渠。当地百姓因白渠而大大受益。}
\leftcol
\jnyuan{三年(丁亥、前94)}
\rightcol
\jnyi{三年(丁亥，公元前94年)}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{春，正月，上行幸甘泉宫。二月，幸东海，获赤雁。幸琅邪，礼日成山，登之罘，浮大海而还。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{春季，正月，汉武帝前往甘泉宫。二月，巡游东海郡，捉到一只赤色大雁。又巡游琅邪郡，在成山拜日，并登上之罘山，然后乘船在海上巡游后返回长安。}
\leftcol
\zhwyuan{是岁，皇子弗陵生。弗陵母曰河间赵，居钩弋宫，任身十四月而生。上曰：“闻昔尧十四月而生，今钩弋亦然。”乃命其所生门曰尧母门。}
\rightcol
\zhwyi{这一年，皇子刘弗陵出生。刘弗陵的母亲是河间人，姓赵，受封为，住在钩弋宫，怀孕十四个月后生刘弗陵。汉武帝说：“听说当年尧是十四个月才出生的，如今赵生这个孩子也是如此。”于是下令将钩弋宫宫门改称尧母门。}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If it breaks at the position you intend, why don't you use `\widowpenalties~3~10000~-1~0` then?

Comment: your red box is 2 lines from the end of a paragraph so `\widowpenalties 2 10000 0` would place a penalty of 10000 to break there, `\widowpenalties 3 10000 -1 0` would place -1 so ecourage a break

Comment: My question is, why the the page overfull the bottom frame rather than break at red place? And need I ecourage a `-1` manually? My book have thousand pages, with `\widowpenalties 2 10000 0`, only a few pages will overfull the bottom frame, most pages can break at third from last line (red place). So that why I ask `\widowpenalties` don't work fine.